# What do the << and >> operator do?

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-shift

I came across some code as noted below and am confused as to what it's doing.

```
hash += (hash << 10);
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftLeft.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Bitwise Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Here's an example from the MDN (linked to above):

```
     9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
                  --------------------------------
9 << 2 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000100100 (base 2) = 36 (base 10)
```

See how the 1s have shifted?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the JavaScript [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> **Left Shift**
>
> a << b
>
> Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.